# Active Menu using Django passing it along templates

Tags: django, django-templates

This example at http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2421/ works as it is.

**Placed in templates/includes/tabs.html**

```
    <ul class="tab-menu">
        <li class="{% if active_tab == 'tab1' %} active{% endif %}"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li class="{% if active_tab == 'tab2' %} active{% endif %}"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li class="{% if active_tab == 'tab3' %} active{% endif %}"><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

**Placed in your page.html template**

```
    {% include "includes/tabs.html" with active_tab='tab1' %}
```

The variable gets passed along from page template to tabs.html.

How would you pass active tab variable from:

```
- page.html (pass active tab1)
    -   extends base.html
        - includes tabs.html (how to get it here.)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `base.html` you could have your `{% block tabs %}`:

```
{% block tabs %}{% endblock %}
```

And in your `page.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block tabs %}
    {% include "includes/tabs.html" with active_tab='tab1' %}
{% endblock %}
```

If this isn't enough DRY for you you can maybe crate a custom [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) for your tabs.